# How to check whether data exist in firebase or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check weather the data exist or not in firebase.

Suppose I want to check weather `vivank` exist or not 
[image: Firebase Database Screenshot]

I used this . But it's not running and not showing any output.

```
const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

function check() {
  theDataToAdd = 'vivank'
  firebaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild(theDataToAdd)) {
      alert('exists');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If you change the code in the callback to `if (snapshot.hasChild(theDataToAdd)) {
      alert('exists');
    } else { alert('does not exist'); }`, does either of those alerts show?

Comment: yes does not exist shows

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why that is. Can you reproduce the problem on a site like jsbin/jsfiddle, so that I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this to check if such data exists in your firebase database or not:

```javascript
Ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasChild(theDataToAdd)) {
    alert('exists');
  }
});
```

But this is a bit inefficient as it would first download all data under `Ref` and then do the check. A bit more efficient solution will be:

```javascript
Ref.child(theDataToAdd).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    alert('exists');
  }
});
```

This is efficient due to the fact that it's a bit more targeted towards the referenced node.

Comment: can you suggest according to my variables like what is `value` etc and what is `ref`

Comment: @MansiShukla try the code 2 and `Ref` is the reference to your database, just make sure that you use ref correctly as in your database there are no nodes except one, check by putting this code.